# document.getElementById dentro de un bucle?

Tags: javascript, ajax, modal

Buenas tengo el siguiente ajax

```
function Cargar() {
    var Url = "action.php";
    var id_Ticket_modal = document.getElementById("id").value; // obtengo la variable que deseo
    var arreglo = {
      "valor": id_Ticket_modal
    };
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: Url,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: arreglo,

    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (console && console.log) {
        console.log("La solicitud se ha completado correctamente.");
        if (typeof(data) === "string") { //Si el valor es un string lo convierte en un json
          data = JSON.parse(data)
        }
        // console.log(data)
        data.forEach(function(element) {
          console.log(element);
          document.getElementById('id_Ticket').value = element.id_Ticket;
          document.getElementById('fecha_Ingreso').value = element.fecha_Ingreso;
          document.getElementById('nom_Maquina').value = element.nom_Maquina;
          document.getElementById('nro_Serie').value = element.nro_Serie;
          document.getElementById('tipo_Tarea').value = element.tipo_Tarea;
          document.getElementById('observacion_data').value = element.observacion;


           document.getElementById('repuesto').value = element.repuesto; //Varios repuestos
           document.getElementById('cantidad').value = element.cantidad; //Variada cantidad


          });
        $('#exampleModalToggle2').modal('show'); //Llamada al segundo modal                                
                            
      }
    }).fail(function() {
      alert("Error al buscar datos");
    });
  }
</script>
```

Lo que hace aquí en el ajax. Hago llamar a los datos a la pagina actions.php obteniendo las variables por id único, que en este caso es id_Ticket.
Y bueno me los trae como un Json para poder trabajarlos y asignarlos a "ID" de un segundo modal que estoy abriendo. En la siguiente imagen se ve como me los trae como un json.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver los traigo como un json. Y en el ajax en la parte del "DONE", las trabajo asignándolas a id con inputs, de la siguiente manera.

```
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          if (console && console.log) {
            console.log("La solicitud se ha completado correctamente.");
            if (typeof(data) === "string") { //Si el valor es un string lo convierte en un json
              data = JSON.parse(data)
            }
            // console.log(data)
            data.forEach(function(element) {
              console.log(element);
              document.getElementById('id_Ticket').value = element.id_Ticket;
              document.getElementById('fecha_Ingreso').value = element.fecha_Ingreso;
              document.getElementById('nom_Maquina').value = element.nom_Maquina;
              document.getElementById('nro_Serie').value = element.nro_Serie;
              document.getElementById('tipo_Tarea').value = element.tipo_Tarea;
              document.getElementById('observacion_data').value = element.observacion;
    
    
               document.getElementById('repuesto').value = element.repuesto; //Varios repuestos
               document.getElementById('cantidad').value = element.cantidad; //Variada cantidad
    
    
              });
```

Bueno al final de todo me abre el modal con los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema ya lo deben suponer. Lo que quiero lograr es que me aparezca en la tabla todos los repuestos que solicitaron. Es decir, como vieron en el Json debería traerme los datos de "TORNILLO" con sus cantidades y solo me trae el dato de palanca.

Tengo un código que me los llama a todos, pero siempre que me salgo del 2 modal y entro de nuevo me repite los datos y así sucesivamente.
En el Ajax solo tienen que cambiar la parte del done con el siguiente código.

```
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (console && console.log) {
        console.log("La solicitud se ha completado correctamente.");
        if (typeof(data) === "string") { //Si el valor es un string lo convierte en un json
          data = JSON.parse(data)
        }
        // console.log(data)
        data.forEach(function(element) {
          console.log(element);
          document.getElementById('id_Ticket').value = element.id_Ticket;
          document.getElementById('fecha_Ingreso').value = element.fecha_Ingreso;
          document.getElementById('nom_Maquina').value = element.nom_Maquina;
          document.getElementById('nro_Serie').value = element.nro_Serie;
          document.getElementById('tipo_Tarea').value = element.tipo_Tarea;
          document.getElementById('observacion_data').value = element.observacion;


          //  document.getElementById('repuesto').value = element.repuesto;
          //  document.getElementById('cantidad').value = element.cantidad;

           $(".table").append(
            
            "<tr>" ,
            $('<th >').text("Repuesto"),
            $('<th >').text("Cantidad"),
            "</tr>" ,
            "<tr>" ,
            $('<td>').text(element.repuesto),
            $('<td>').text(element.cantidad),
            "</tr>"

          );
          });
   

        $('#exampleModalToggle2').modal('show'); //Llamada al segundo modal                                
                            
      }
```

El código de arriba al final me abre el segundo modal y me trae los siguiente datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el problema está si vuelvo a presionar la función "CARGAR" que lo asigno a un botón.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL ELEMENTO TABLE ES CON ID

```
<table class="table mt-3 pb-3" style="    margin-bottom: -20px;">
         
          </table>
```

Comment: La idea no es ocultar el boton cargar() porque quien esté trabajando. Siempre querrá ver el detalle del ticket.

Comment: déjanos ver el html de ese elemento .table, porque si esta separado del de arriba es tan fácil como inicializarlo antes del bucle borrando su contenido, y en caso de que esten todos en la misma tabla entonces le pones una clase a los **tr** (por ejemplo: `"<tr class="repuestos">" ,`) y antes del bucle lo borras con `$('.repuestos').remove()` pues se volverá a rellenar durante el bucle

Comment: @masterguru lo intentare, hay deje el elemento table no tiene thead o tbody,  no se si eso afecta.

Comment: la pregunta es... ese table es solo para los repuestos o es una continuación de lo que vemos arriba?  Si es solo para repuestos pon esto antes del bucle:  `$('.table').empty()` para vaciarlo antes de rellenarlo de nuevo con los repuestos del bucle (suponiendo que ninguna más usa esa clase `table` o bien le agregas una nueva clase llamada `table_repuestos` para diferenciarla del resto y haces un  `$('.table_repuestos').empty()` antes del bucle)

Comment: Si tuviera thead y tbody entonces para eliminar su contenido sin afectar al thead lo harias así: `$('.table_repuestos tbody').empty()` borrando solo el tbody

Answer (score 0):

@masterguru

```
function Cargar() {
    var Url = "actions.php";
    var id_Ticket_modal = document.getElementById("id").value; // obtengo la variable que deseo
    var arreglo = {
      "valor": id_Ticket_modal
    };
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: Url,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: arreglo,

    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (console && console.log) {
        console.log("La solicitud se ha completado correctamente.");
        if (typeof(data) === "string") { //Si el valor es un string lo convierte en un json
          data = JSON.parse(data)
        }
        // console.log(data)
        // $('.repuestos').remove()
        $(".table_Repuestos").empty() // Limpio la tabla para volver a llamar.

        data.forEach(function(element) {
          console.log(element);
          document.getElementById('id_Ticket').value = element.id_Ticket;
          document.getElementById('fecha_Ingreso').value = element.fecha_Ingreso;
          document.getElementById('nom_Maquina').value = element.nom_Maquina;
          document.getElementById('nro_Serie').value = element.nro_Serie;
          document.getElementById('tipo_Tarea').value = element.tipo_Tarea;
          document.getElementById('observacion_data').value = element.observacion;


          //  document.getElementById('repuesto').value = element.repuesto;
          //  document.getElementById('cantidad').value = element.cantidad;
          $(".table_Repuestos").append(
            
            "<tr>" ,
            $('<th >').text("Repuesto"),
            $('<th >').text("Cantidad"),
            "</tr>" ,
            "<tr>" ,
            $('<td>').text(element.repuesto),
            $('<td>').text(element.cantidad),
            "</tr>"

          );
          });

        $('#exampleModalToggle2').modal('show'); //Llamada al segundo modal                                
                            
      }
    }).fail(function() {
      alert("Error al buscar datos");
    });
  }
```

Amigo gracias te pasaste, me gustaría tener tu lógica  me sirvió, ahora si no se van sumando los datos.

Así se ve ahora, claro que saque la clase de "table" de Bootstrap. Y se ve de esta manera, pero ahora sí, estuve casi 2 horas tratando de buscar esta solución al problema .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No hace falta que quites la clase **table** de bootstrap a esa tabla, ni mucho menos, que ahora queda fea... lo que te decia era que **agregaras** una nueva clase solo para esa tabla, y que lo dejaras así: `class="table table_Repuestos mt-3 pb-3"`... de esta forma esa clase hace como si fuera un identificador único hacia ella y la podemos vaciar tal como has puesto en esta respuesta cuando queramos sin afectar a las otras, pues las otras no tienen la table_Repuestos.  A diferencia de los **id=** las clases pueden ser muchas y si se quiere algunas únicas, haciendo el mismo papel que un **id**.